# Checking if time is between two intervals

Tags: scripts

Using

```
CZ=$(date +%H%M)
if [ 0000 < "$CZ" < 18000 ]
then
echo "1"
else
echo "2"
fi
```

It ends with

```
line 2: 1156: No such file or directory
2
```

(`1156` is time script ran 11:56)

The purpose of it is to check whether my current time is between 0:00 and 18:00 in this case.

Comment: See http://unix.stackexchange.com/a/118857/70524

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this condition:

`if [[ $CZ < 1800 && $CZ > 0000 ]]`